# Does Improved Overrun prevent AoO or not?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

In the 3.5 Player's Handbook, the entry for the feat Improved Overrun on Table 5-1: Feats (p 90-91) states the benefit as:

> +4 bonus on overrun attempts; no attack of opportunity

The full description for the feat (p 96) describes the benefit as:

> Benefit: When you attempt to overrun an opponent, the target may  not choose to avoid you. You also gain a +4 bonus on your Strength check to knock down your opponent.

The SRD posted on d20srd.org agrees with the full entry for the feat. Is the table just incorrect or do all benefits apply? I have looked in a couple of errata, and while there are adjustments to the overrun action, there is no change to the Improved Overrun feat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Table's Incorrect; The Text's Correct

From the errata to the *Player's Handbook* [here](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20040125a)

> **Errata Rule: Primary Sources**
>   When you find a disagreement between two *D&D* rules sources, unless an official errata file says otherwise, the primary source is correct. *One example of a primary/secondary source is text taking precedence over a table entry.*

Emphasis mine. So while the table says that the feat Improved Overrun (*PH* 96) prevents the attack of opportunity, the text doesn't, and the text is what matters.